# How to move Inline SVG to css

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this inline SVG that I got working, and now want to move it to an external file so I can use it in other places.

(It's a simple drag icon.)

https://gist.run/?id=de197c5eb19bc35bf7f537f7aab345a8

How do I do that?

```
 <svg style="height:16px; width:16px;" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M14,5.5c0,1.7-1.3,3-3,3s-3-1.3-3-3s1.3-3,3-3S14,3.8,14,5.5z M21,8.5c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3s-1.3-3-3-3s-3,1.3-3,3S19.3,8.5,21,8.5z M11,12.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S12.7,12.5,11,12.5z M21,12.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S22.7,12.5,21,12.5z M11,22.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S12.7,22.5,11,22.5z M21,22.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S22.7,22.5,21,22.5z"></path></svg>
```

I am not trying to customize it, just reuse it by putting it in a .css file.

Comment: @VicJordan, I looked at that, but it seems to be talking about customizing SVG in different places.

Comment: You can include an SVG image in your CSS by using a Data URL

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a SVG template and use it at multiple places.

Below is example:

```css
svg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- SVG template -->
<div style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px;">
  <svg style="height:16px; width:16px;" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 18 15" id="sample">
    <path d="M14,5.5c0,1.7-1.3,3-3,3s-3-1.3-3-3s1.3-3,3-3S14,3.8,14,5.5z M21,8.5c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3s-1.3-3-3-3s-3,1.3-3,3S19.3,8.5,21,8.5z M11,12.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S12.7,12.5,11,12.5z M21,12.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S22.7,12.5,21,12.5z M11,22.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S12.7,22.5,11,22.5z M21,22.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S22.7,22.5,21,22.5z"></path>
    </symbol>
  </svg>
</div>
          


<!-- and use it whenever you want -->
<svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sample"></use></svg>

<svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sample"></use></svg>
```

For more information please check [**this**](https://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/) article.

Comment: That is really cool, but I want to put it in an external file, not inline it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this working by putting the SVG in a file: grip.svg:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="height:16px; width:16px;" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
 <path d="M14,5.5c0,1.7-1.3,3-3,3s-3-1.3-3-3s1.3-3,3-3S14,3.8,14,5.5z M21,8.5c1.7,0,3-1.3,3-3s-1.3-3-3-3s-3,1.3-3,3S19.3,8.5,21,8.5z M11,12.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S12.7,12.5,11,12.5z M21,12.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S22.7,12.5,21,12.5z M11,22.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S12.7,22.5,11,22.5z M21,22.5c-1.7,0-3,1.3-3,3s1.3,3,3,3s3-1.3,3-3S22.7,22.5,21,22.5z">
</path>
</svg>
```

Then used it like this:

```
 <img style="height:16px;width:16px;" src="/assets/images/grippy.svg" />
```